# jquery to hide long quotes with show more/less

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come up against an interesting barrier in implementing a jquery show/hide quotes link, for when quotes end up annoyingly long. So, if a quote is too long, hide it with a show link.

A simple "each" check on a class given to quotes was easy. The problem is, quotes can contain quotes and that will break it, since it will attempt to do it on each quote, instead of the top one.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
// hide long quotes
var showChar = 350;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Click for more";
var lesstext = "Click for less";
$('.comment_quote').each(function() 
{
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) 
    {
        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

I can't think of a solution that would both loop through the page to pick them up AND pick the top most quote with that "comment_quote" class each time.

Comment: What is the top one you are speaking about? Also what is it about the text that can break it? Do they contain html or something?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or add html and css in order to create an evidence?

Comment: if you control the quotes, just remove the quotes and add them using jQuery.  If you don't control the quotes then you can remove them before your problem happens `var c = content.replace(/'/g, '').substr(0, showChar);` and then add them back in manually when you are done with your manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will help you :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

<body>
<script>
    $(function () {
            var text = $('#text').text();
            var nw=[];
            var leng = text.length;
            var result="";
            if(leng>50){
                 nw[0] = text.substr(0, 50);
                 nw[1] = "  <a href='#' id='btn'>more..</a>";
                 nw[2] = text.substr(50);
                result = nw[0] + nw[1];
                $('#text').html(result);
            }
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            result = nw[0] + nw[2];
            $('#text').html(result);
        });


    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```